# Shared Google Sheet with a Script not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, permissions

I am not a Google expert. 
I have a Google Sheet file with certain data that have to be managed by users. 
Within this file, I developed a script that runs whenever a button is clicked, that basically takes some input data (manually inserted by users) and send them to another tab within the same file.

I created the script by using the Google Sheet path: Extensions -> Apps Script and then linking the script to the image button. 
My script does not involve Web App, nor HTML nor anything else. It is just a data manager within the same file.

I have an issue when I **share the file with another user**. When he clicks the button, the script is running but never finishes.
I am pretty sure that I have some permission issues, but I can't figure out how to fix it. 
Thank you all!

Comment: Please provide [mcve]

Comment: I don't know how to provide an example.
I can provide a shared google sheet with a red button not working (for another user different from me)

Comment: You got any solution? I'm facing same problem.